# how to group the array of data based on multiple values?

Tags: arrays, group-by, lodash

I want to group the data based on the type and type_id
Here is the array

```
var addArray = [
                    {
                        "id": 24,
                        "language_id": 3,
                        "type": "service",
                        "type_id": 2,
                        "key": "service seeker",
                        "value": " need service"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 23,
                        "language_id": 3,
                        "type": "service",
                        "type_id": 2,
                        "key": "phone",
                        "value": "phone number"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 24,
                        "language_id": 3,
                        "type": "service",
                        "type_id": 7,
                        "key": "tester",
                        "value": "service tester"
                    }
                    {
                        "id": 19,
                        "language_id": 3,
                        "type": "offer",
                        "type_id": 4,
                        "key": "source",
                        "value": "resource"
                    }
                ]
```

I have tried `let result = _.groupBy(addArray,'type')` it is grouping the data based on type but I need to group by type as well as type_id

Expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the a flat grouping based on two or more properties, use the `_.groupBy()` callback to combine the properties to a string:

```js
const addArray = [{"id":24,"language_id":3,"type":"service","type_id":2,"key":"service seeker","value":" need service"},{"id":23,"language_id":3,"type":"service","type_id":2,"key":"phone","value":"phone number"},{"id":24,"language_id":3,"type":"service","type_id":7,"key":"tester","value":"service tester"},{"id":19,"language_id":3,"type":"offer","type_id":4,"key":"source","value":"resource"}]

const result = _.groupBy(addArray, o => `${o.type}-${o.type_id}`)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If you need a multi level grouping, start by grouping by the `type`, then map the groups with `_.values()`, and group them again by `type_id`:

```js
const { flow, partialRight: pr, groupBy, mapValues } = _

const fn = flow(
  pr(groupBy, 'type'),
  pr(mapValues, g => groupBy(g, 'type_id'))
)

const addArray = [{"id":24,"language_id":3,"type":"service","type_id":2,"key":"service seeker","value":" need service"},{"id":23,"language_id":3,"type":"service","type_id":2,"key":"phone","value":"phone number"},{"id":24,"language_id":3,"type":"service","type_id":7,"key":"tester","value":"service tester"},{"id":19,"language_id":3,"type":"offer","type_id":4,"key":"source","value":"resource"}]

const result = fn(addArray)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```